# Iter through XML tags and get tag inside that attribute - Python

Tags: python, xml

I'm looking for child tag values in xml data, my code below gets me all the values for tags "color" inside "info" in xml data, but I'm looking for a iteration,

if color = yellow, i need to get it's rank only.

****My Code:****

```
xmldata = '''
 <FullGroup>
    <color>General</color>
    <link>url</link>
    <three>test</three>
    <four>
      <info>
        <color>yellow</color>
        <rank>100</rank>
        <place>first</place>
      </info>
      <info>
        <color>red</color>
        <rank>500</rank>
        <place>second</place>
      </info>
     </four>
 </FullGroup>'''  

xml = ElementTree.fromstring(xmldata)
for color in xml.findall('.//info/color'):
   print color.text

output: 
yellow
red

Required output:
100
```

Thanks in Advance ..

Answer (score 1):

You could use `zip()` like so:

```
for color, rank in zip(xml.findall('.//info/color'), xml.findall('.//info/rank')):
    if color.text == 'yellow':
        print(rank.text)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'findall'.... Error, is it reading xml data as string ?

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath expression is wrong. To get the `rank` children of all `info` elements which have a  child named `color` with the `text()` value "yellow", change

```
xml = ElementTree.fromstring(xmldata)
for color in xml.findall('.//info/color'):
   print color.text
```

to

```
xml = ElementTree.fromstring(xmldata)
for curRank in xml.findall('.//info[color="yellow"]/rank'):
   print curRank.text
```

**Output is:**

```
100
```